# how can you sort by date for an ArrayList with TreeMap as value

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

in my code I have `ArrayList<TreeMap<String, Object>>`. What `TreeMap` would have is the key and value. there is a key named **sent_date** with the value in format of `yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. I can't find a way to sort this list...Can someone please help? thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you want your list sorted?  What have you already tried?

Comment: Are you saying that each `TreeMap` element contains only 1 entry? Why not just use a `TreeMap` and forgo the `ArrayList` entirely if so?

Comment: Would a guava Table be a better data structure? http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html

Comment: `TreeMap` has more entries, and sent_date is one of them.

Comment: when I tried to loop through the `ArrayList` and print out the values in the `TreeMap`, I wish to have them in order by sent_date. I was thinking this can be done right after elements are all added to the `ArrayList` so I don't have to change my loop

Comment: What is `sent_date`? Is it a class? A variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`, where you have to implement a `Comparator<Map<String,?>>` to do what you need (i.e. retrieve the `sent_date` from two maps and compare those).

Comment: I'll also +1 anyone who posts a concise implementation with the new Java8 features. This must be possible now without much boilerplate.

Comment: comparator is the part I don't get it...Can you please give me more example?

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, this would be (for a sort that modifies the list):

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> LocalDateTime.parse(m.get("sent_date"), format)));
```

Or if you want to keep the original list:

```
newList = list.stream()
              .sorted(Comparator.comparing(...))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: humm...I have java7 :(